# Why does Rails change the time returned from a Postgres function to UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, rails-postgresql

Can anyone explain this? It is as if Rails is overriding Postgres and telling it to work in UTC when I want it to work in my local timezonw?

I have a Postgres function which returns the local time as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_lib_now() RETURNS TIMESTAMP AS $$
DECLARE
l_now TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
l_now = LOCALTIMESTAMP;

-- Debug code that writes to local file
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x;
CREATE TABLE x (a TEXT);
INSERT INTO x (a) VALUES (l_now);
COPY (SELECT x.a AS localnow, LOCALTIMESTAMP AS local_timestamp, LOCALTIMESTAMP::date         AS local_date, LOCALTIME AS local_time, CURRENT_DATE AS current_date, CURRENT_TIME AS current_time FROM x) TO 'C:\temp\a.txt' WITH CSV HEADER;

-- Success
RETURN l_now;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I run the function from PSQL with `SELECT fn_lib_now();`

I get the result in PSQL : `"2013-05-07 18:59:43.916"`` (the correct local time)

and my debug output (reformatted) is:

```
localnow,                 local_timestamp,           local_date,    local_time,      current_date,  current_time
2013-05-07 18:59:43.916,  2013-05-07  18:59:43.916,  2013-05-07,   18:59:43.916,    2013-05-07,    18:59:43.916+10
```

Note that all of the times returned match the local time.

If however, I call the function from Rails using:

```
begin
  result = (self.class.find_by_sql(["SELECT fn_lib_now() AS nowout"])).first
rescue ActiveRecord::WrappedDatabaseException => e
  raise self.class.handle_sql_error(e)
end
puts result[:nowout]
```

I get the return value: `'2013-05-07 09:11:10.142'`

and my debug output (reformatted) is:

```
localnow,                  local_timestamp,         local_date,  local_time,     current_date,  current_time
2013-05-07 09:11:10.142,  2013-05-07 09:11:10.142,  2013-05-07,  09:11:10.142,     2013-05-07,    09:11:10.142+00
```

Note that all of the times match UTC (which is 10 hours behind my Australian timezone).

Why should the same function return different results when called from PSQL (Local Time) and Rails (UTC), especially when my application.rb has the line:

```
config.time_zone = 'Brisbane'
```

Comment: Consider using `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) instead of `timestamp without time zone` (plain `timestamp`). The semantics of the latter generally make more sense unless you're particularly concerned about capturing details like which of the two local 1am's it was during a DST transition - and even then, you need to store the tz offset as well as the `timestamp` for it to be useful. (No guarantee this'll help ActiveRecord not be crazy, it's just generally a good idea anyway).